# React native Layout animation for animations

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I'm trying to use layout animation to animate my view when i delete an item from the list.
Here's what i current code

```
  removeItem = (data) => {
      LayoutAnimation.configureNext(LayoutAnimation.Presets.spring);
      follow(data);
  }
```

but i get this error[image]

Comment: is the error coz some index calculation issue? like  there are only 5 elements but its taking index 6

Comment: If you let us see more code we can help you more